# Referencing an object with an unknown model-type with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/index.html) is it possible to have a field that references another object, when the model/type of that document is unknown?

For example, I have the models: Photos, Comments, Submissions, Posts, etc., and I would like to have a Like model that refers back to them:

```
var Like = new Mongoose.Schema({
  // What would the value of `ref` be, should it just be left out?
  target: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: '*' }
});
```

From what I understand, `ref` needs to be a Model. I could leave it out all together, but would I still get the benefit of the Mongoose's [populate method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take.

## 1. Pass in the value of ref when you call populate

Based on the section [*Populating across Databases*](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#cross-db-populate). When you call `populate`, you can specify the model you want to use.

```
Like.find().populate({
  path: 'target',
  model: 'Photo'   
})
```

This requires that you know the model you want before you populate.

## 2. Store the value of ref together with the target

Based on the section [*Dynamic References*](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref).

You need to first adjust the `target` to something similar to the following:

```
var Like = new Mongoose.Schema({
  target: {
    kind: String,
    item: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      refPath: 'target.kind'
    }
  }
});
```

`target.kind` is the value of "ref" that will be used for `populate`, and `target.item` is the ObjectId. We use `refPath` instead of `ref` for dynamic references.

Then, when you call `populate`, you will instead do something like:

```
Like.find().populate('target.item')
```

Note that we populate `'target.item'` as opposed to just `'target'`.